# "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" when updating chart

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, ng2-charts

I'm trying to refresh a ng2-charts 's chart, but I receive this error: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.".

This is the piece of code where I try to refresh the chart:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this._updateDatasets(changes.data.currentValue);
    this.isEmptyData = !(this.datasets && this.datasets.length > 0);
    if (this.datasets[0]['label'] !== undefined) {
      this.generateChartColors();
      this.buildDatasetLabels();
      if (this._chart) {
        console.log('changes: ', changes);
        console.log('labels:', this.labels);
        console.log('datasets: ', this.datasets)
        console.log('chart: ', this._chart);
        this._chart.refresh()
      }
    } else {
      this.isLoading = false;
    }
  }
```

All the variables I print (`changes`, `this.labels`, `this.datasets`) have the correct data. `this.labels` are binded to `this._chart` in the `this.buildDatasetLabels()` function and this.datasets is directly tied to the chart dataset in the template.

These are all the `console.log` and `this._chart` seems wrong:

[image: console logs]

This is the error:

[image: chart's bug]

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I initialize all the variables of the chart in my component (in the template I'm only accessing to the max and the min of yAxes's ticks), but I'm still getting the same error but, this time, the chart seems correct.

[image: chart error]

These are my chart's variables initialization:

```
datasets = {data: [], label: '', hidden: false}

chartColors: Array<any> = [{ // Default colors
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.2)',
    borderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,1)',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(148,159,177,0.8)'
  }];

labels: Array<any> = ['00'];
```

And this is my template:

```
<div class="loading" [ngClass]="{ 'active': isLoading }"><img src="../../assets/img/cloud_load.gif"></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="row">
  <div *ngIf="isEmptyData" class="overlay">
    <h3 class="no-data">No data in this time frame.</h3>
  </div>
  <canvas name="canvas-historical-pipe-data" class="canvas-monitored-pipes_historical_data" baseChart height="350"
          [datasets]="datasets" [options]="chartOptions" [labels]="labels"
          [colors]="chartColors" [legend]="showLegend" [chartType]="chartType"
          (chartHover)="onChartHover($event)" (chartClick)="onChartClick($event)"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="row">
      <form class="col-xs-12 center" [formGroup]="degreeForm">
        <img class="svg_icon temperature" src="assets/img/icons/icon_thermometer_default.svg">
        <label for="startTemp" class="margin-left">From: </label>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input id="startTemp" formControlName="startDegree" matInput (change)="chartScaleChange()"
                 [value]="chartOptions.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min">
        </mat-form-field>
        <label for="endTemp"> To: </label>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input id="endTemp" formControlName="endDegree" matInput (change)="chartScaleChange()"
                 [value]="chartOptions.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max">
        </mat-form-field>
      </form>
      <div class="col-xs-12 center">
        <button
          [ngClass]="{ 'enabled-button': !dataAutofitted, 'clickable': !dataAutofitted, 'disabled-button': dataAutofitted }"
          (click)="autofit()"
          [disabled]="dataAutofitted">Autofit
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 margin-top" *ngFor="let pipe of data; let pipeIndex = index"
           (click)="hideOrShowPipeData(pipeIndex)">
        <i class="fas fa-circle" [ngStyle]="{'color': chartColors[pipeIndex]['borderColor']}"></i>
        {{ pipe.label }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your html your referring a variable using `.[0]` operator which is null or undefined.

To avoid these kind of common issues, you have initialize all the variables which you are going to use in the templates.

For eg: in the blew code ( your ngOnInit) the line number 5 will break because you are accessing the `this.datasets[0]['label']` and if the dataset is null or unbdefined, then it will through an unhandled exception. The same kind of mistake may exist in your html file, which caused the error mentioned above.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this._updateDatasets(changes.data.currentValue);
    this.isEmptyData = !(this.datasets && this.datasets.length > 0);
    if (this.datasets[0]['label'] !== undefined) {
      this.generateChartColors();
      this.buildDatasetLabels();
      if (this._chart) {
        console.log('changes: ', changes);
        console.log('labels:', this.labels);
        console.log('datasets: ', this.datasets)
        console.log('chart: ', this._chart);
        this._chart.refresh()
      }
    } else {
      this.isLoading = false;
    }
  }
```

So, as a solution always, use a null check before accessing any child. And never use `variable[index].property` in a hard coded way in your template unless you are initializing the 0th value from your code.

Comment: It's pretty clear. In your monitored-pipes.component.html, Line 54, you are accessing the child of an array while the array it is undefined.

Also, I could see you are accessing a lot of child objects like `chartOptions.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min`, which should not be used. Because, in case the `chartOptions.scales` are not defined, your application breaks. 

So, move these kind of value access-or in to your `.ts` as a function. You could call this function for getting the values, and in that function you could add the null checks.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I fixed in another way, loading the data directly in the component and not passed from the parent. I'll improve the code, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So from the error `this.dataSets` is undefined. You are console logging it after you do the following

```
      this.generateChartColors();
      this.buildDatasetLabels();
      console logs....
```

So I can only assume that one of these functions is putting data into `this.dataSets`. Try adding a `console.log` above this line `if (this.datasets[0]['label'] !== undefined) {` to check if the variable is `undefined` before you check it in the `if` statement.

If it is, you need to make sure it is defined before accessing the `[0]` property.

Hope this helps.